# Cant run react-native app with run-android on emulator

Tags: react-native

So I'm trying to run the react-native on my terminal but i keep getting different errors and wondering whats happening and i keep fixing and then more keep appearing but the latest one that I've faced is about my react-native-track-player and im using the github one in my package.json

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
```

Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-track-player'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-track-player:classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
> Required by:
> project :react-native-track-player
> > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
> > Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/172.217.20.142] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install debug again.

```
cd android
./gradlew.bat installDebug
```

And then run again.

Answer (score 0):

dl.google.com is blocked for some countries!
try

```
1) Used a proxy and defined the variables http_proxy and http_proxy on the terminal.

2) Then run the "react-native run-android".
```